# How can I find out the name of my VS2010 solution / Application from inside my C# program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I know this is a strange request but I have code that is shared between different solutions. When I run the code I would like it to act "slightly" different.

Is there a way that I could check what bin/application/solution is being executed?

Hope someone has some good ideas.

Thanks,

Mandy Wilson (FPL West Palm Beach)

Comment: What do you mean by "Solution / Application`? A solution is just a group of projects.  What is your project?

Comment: This is invariably the wrong approach.  Just add a public static property to your class, the app is no trouble setting it and enable this 'slightly' different behavior.  Second best is a configuration file that you find back in the app's install folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` to find the `Assembly` instance that the user launched.
You can then check its `AssemblyName` or `Location`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your actual question on solution name, but can't you just put a different marker in the Config file for each solution, and have the logic switch based on that? Say:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="AppType" value="SomeType1" />
</appSettings>
```

Then read that setting in your shared code and have it behave different based on the actual value of that key.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use settings and configure the behavior explicitly on deployment.

Keywords are App Config and the `System.Configuration` namespace.

#### Application Settings:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="AppType" value="SomeType" />
</appSettings>
```

#### Get the value:

```
var appType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppType"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using meta information from the executing program is, I think, not the best approach.  Generally, I'd approach this one of two ways. First, using configuration files.  Store the information that's different for each solution in a configuration file and use the configuration file settings to drive program behavior.  If you're unwilling to allow the user to change program behavior through the configuration file, then I'd use a plugin architecture and provide the configuration via the plugin.  Your common code would depend on the plugin interface and in each solution you'd simply construct a different version of the plugin that contains the appropriate configuration information.

Comment: Assembly names will not change on rename.

Comment: @SLaks - the question reads "application name" in the title.  I had assumed that it was a case of "zip/unzip" where the same code is being used but the action of the program differs based on what name is used when it's being invoked.  A closer reading shows that's probably not the case.  I still think that it's better not to have to use meta information to determine how the program behaves.  I've clarified.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your trying to you check the ProductName of each application.

```
if (Application.ProductName == "App1")
{
    // Action
}
else if (Application.ProductName == "App2")
{
    // Other Actions
}
```

I hope i understood what you'r trying to do.